# Scrapy not able to scrape for the next page

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I wanted to scrape the information for the following pages, however, the code only allows me to scrape the information from the first page.

My code is as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from ..items import PropertyItem

class Starprop(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'starprop'
allowed_domains = ['starproperty.com']
start_urls = ['https://www.starproperty.my/to-buy/search?max_price=1000000%2B&new_launch_checkbox=on&sub_sales_checkbox=on&auction_checkbox=on&listing=For%20Sale&sort=latest&page=1']


def parse(self, response):
    item = PropertyItem ()
    property_list = response.css('.mb-4 div')

    for property in property_list:
        property_name = property.css ('.property__name::text').extract()
        property_price = property.css('.property__price::text').extract()
        property_location = property.css ('.property__location::text').extract()
        property_agent = property.css('.property__agentdetails .property__agentdetails span:nth-child(1)::text').extract()
        property_phone = property.css ('.property__agentcontacts a span::text').extract()

        item['property_name']= property_name
        item['property_price']= property_price
        item['property_location'] = property_location
        item['property_agent'] = property_agent
        item['property_phone'] = property_phone

        yield item

        next_page = response.css('.page-item:nth-child(10) .page-link::attr(href)').get()

    if next_page is not None:
        yield response.follow(next_page, callback = self.parse)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's all about your `allowed_domains` (but you need to fix your indent too). Also I'm sure that you want to define your item **inside** your loop:

```
class Starprop(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'starprop'
    allowed_domains = ['starproperty.my']
    start_urls = ['https://www.starproperty.my/to-buy/search?max_price=1000000%2B&new_launch_checkbox=on&sub_sales_checkbox=on&auction_checkbox=on&listing=For%20Sale&sort=latest&page=1']


    def parse(self, response):

        property_list = response.css('.mb-4 div')

        for property in property_list:
            property_name = property.css ('.property__name::text').extract()
            property_price = property.css('.property__price::text').extract()
            property_location = property.css ('.property__location::text').extract()
            property_agent = property.css('.property__agentdetails .property__agentdetails span:nth-child(1)::text').extract()
            property_phone = property.css ('.property__agentcontacts a span::text').extract()
            item = PropertyItem ()
            item['property_name']= property_name
            item['property_price']= property_price
            item['property_location'] = property_location
            item['property_agent'] = property_agent
            item['property_phone'] = property_phone

            yield item

        next_page = response.css('.page-item:nth-child(10) .page-link::attr(href)').get()

        if next_page:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback = self.parse)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe due to indent?
try change:

```
    yield item

    next_page = response.css('.page-item:nth-child(10) .page-link::attr(href)').get()

if next_page is not None:
    yield response.follow(next_page, callback = self.parse)
```

to

```
    yield item

    next_page = response.css('.page-item:nth-child(10) .page-link::attr(href)').get()

    if next_page is not None:
        yield response.follow(next_page, callback = self.parse)
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried your suggestion but only still not able to scrape the second page. Is the selector for my second page incorrect or I missed out on any other codes?

Comment: pls print every thing out and have a look what the `next_page` is